# PHP How to correctly handle critical errors notification on a production server.

Tags: php, error-handling, runtime-error, production-environment

Generally errors are log and such. But what should I do with important errors that need attention on a production server. For example if I was deleting a series of ORM models in a process and somewhere during the process a model fails to delete. I would want the process to delete as many objects as possible and not throw any exceptions to the user. I would also want the developers or admin to be notified of any important errors so they can be instantly fixed.

In the past I had added in script that would email me the error under certain circumstances. If I was in a dev environment it would just throw and exception, however when in production it would die silently and email the error.

Is there some for of way to high-lite certain exceptions as more critical and hence can enable the developers to take action? Could I create a more generic solution. EG if a critical error/exception was thrown then this is always emailed to admin on production, else it follows normal procedure (such as a log).

There are probably some amazing packages that will provide a solution but I'm looking for something more native if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can put up `htaccess` file on your site root with the following lines.

```
# PHP error handling for production servers
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

Do not place `error_log` on public accessible location.

Answer (score 0):

I would log them. There exist several tools which are able to monitor logfiles and which can react on certain patterns.

https://www.loggly.com/docs/file-monitoring/

https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#file_content_testing

And many more

Answer (score 0):

[PSR-3](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) was defined to handle this sort of situation. If you use a compliant logging interface like [Monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog), you can define how different error levels are handled in each environment. Perhaps on develop you want to display everything on the screen, while on live you might hide everything below CRITICAL and send a [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) or [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) alert for everything above.

Comment: Ok so really I need to get other plugins/packages involved to run this correctly.

Comment: You don't *need* to, no -- but you'll save yourself a ton of work if you do.